# How to delete system-image app programatically?

Tags: android

guys.

I am trying to delete programatically system-image apps.
I know there is deletePackages() in PM and can delete data-image apps through this API.
Is there any good way to delete system-image app or at least initialize their update-part?

Thanks

Comment: System image apps? You mean android system apps like LatinIME.apk

Comment: You cant. You require root access for that.

Comment: Yes,I mean apps that is on system/app or system/priv-app.

Comment: Now I searched proccess in Settings app. If there is some update in system-app, when calling deletePackages() towards that app, is it's update cleared?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched this theme by my self and concluded the following.

deletePackages() in PackageManager can delete the followings.
 - Apps in data/app.
 - The update part of apps in system/app and system/priv-app.

Apps in system/ can not be deleted progmatically through any API.
If you want to delete them, do FOTA.

Thanks